# Ubuntu mysql Dreamweaver 403 error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, dreamweaver, ubuntu-14.04

I am having trouble conecting to a mysql server that is runing on ubuntu 14.04. i can log into phpmyadmin and upload webpages via ftp but when i go to create a record set and define a database i get a 403 access forbiden. does any one have any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

A 403 error doesn't mean your script is having trouble connecting to the database server, it means your client (the web browser) is not permitted to access the file/web page you're trying to access.

Most likely your permissions aren't set properly on the files you've uploaded by FTP. Check the owner and permissions and verify that they're appropriate for your situation (for instance, on my system files are 644 and directories are 755 and the file owner doesn't matter. Your mileage may vary).